# Tomcat logs showing "sessionFactoryImpl Returning a Reference to the SessionFactory" multiple times

Tags: entity-framework, hibernate, jpa, sessionfactory

I have hibernate entity with multiple reference entities in hibernate model class and while trying to fetch any entity in spring-hibernate application(c3po pooling and transaction management enabled) getting tomcat multiple log entries with

**[SessionFactoryImpl:getReference(1154)] - Returning a Reference to the SessionFactory**

I have tried with new entity with no reference to test and did not see any log entry for sessionFactoryImpl:getReference in tomcat logs but when i tried with one reference in it that time an entry was there in logs.

Maybe it is dependent on how many reference entities you have in your hibernate model class. when you fire any query that time hibernate sessionFactory creates proxy objects for each reference entities and return back it to session/sessionFactory object when it is executed.

Is it related to transaction management or sessionFactory . if yes ,is there any way i can disable or manage these log entries in tomcat.